# How to append columns to other columns in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have two hash inputs, each has completely different columns. Say hashInput_1 has columns called

`One | Two | Three | Four | Five`

and hashInput_2 has columns called:

`Six | Seven | Eight`

Each hash input has the same number of rows. I just need to combine them into one excel document or flow so that the columns and all of the data gets correctly joined. I know talend can append rows, but I need to append columns so that the new schema is columns `One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight` with all of the data in the appropriate columns.

Comment: Is there a common key between them?

Comment: No common columns between them.

Comment: Every time the same amout of row?

Comment: Yes same amount of rows. Row 1 in the first file will have information for the same person as the first row in the second file, and so on. So they just need to be appended vertically.

Comment: You can try to add column ID increment it like 1 to X on the two hashinput and do a join on the ID column in a tmap

Comment: Do I need to increment in both hash inputs?

Comment: You Need to add à Column to each input with a sequence to increment id and join in tmap on this two column

Comment: Okay I have added the sequence counter to both. Not entirely sure what you mean by join in tmap? This is different than tJoin?

Comment: I have update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more column ID in each of the schema of hashinput.

In the lookup increment this column with a sequence. (See in tjavarow code).

In the tmap increment another sequence and do a join betwen the two ID column.

So first line of one hashinput (ID 1) will join first line other hashinput (ID 1).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!!